# Change currently displayed directory in Windows explorer (jump to sibling directory)

Tags: vbscript, explorer

I would like to know how to change the currently displayed directory in an explorer view.  The purpose of this is for quick navigation to a sibling directory from the currently displayed directory.

I'll derive the new path from the cwd of the explorer view. So

```
c:/teapot/magnet/FOO/duck/barbecue/gyroscope/potato
```

might become

```
c:/teapot/magnet/BAR/duck/barbecue/gyroscope/potato
```

and I'll set update the current explorer view to display that path.

*FWIW The path update from `FOO` to `BAR` would simply be hard wired for my purposes*

What I *don't* want to do is either of:

- open a new explorer view with the new path
- affect any other existing explorer views that may be open

Comment: Do you know about the [IShellBrowser::BrowseObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775113.aspx) method?

Comment: @Neil Is that accessible using VBScript though, is it registered with COM? Otherwise it's write your own COM exposed wrapper for it.

Comment: Probably. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/05/435657.aspx might help.